# deploy rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

Hey
I'm afraid I should ask a rookie question :

After push my app to heroku. I got error of no database

This is the command I use

> heroku rake db:migrate

My app can run locally with no problem, but I notice the database file only in development. 
and my test evironment only use `rails server` and `localhost:3000`

anyone tell me how to make the database in production mode in heroku.

Thanks

here's the heroku log file:

here's the logs

> Started GET "/drummers/1" for
>   221.9.247.14 at Sat Dec 18 06:17:40 -0800 2010  Processing by DrummersController#show as HTML 
>   Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}  Completed in
>   167ms
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't
>   find Drummer with ID=1): 
>   app/controllers/drummers_controller.rb:11:in
>   `show'
>
> I think it may due to the datebase,config file, become I use sqlite3 in local test, and all the migration file is development prefix,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not telling you that you have no Database.

It's telling you that it can't find a specific record

```
(Couldn't find Drummer with ID=1):
```

It's likely that you have code that's doing `Drummer.find(1)` and that doesn't exist on your production environment.

Recommend you either:

- create a seeds file (heroku rake db:seed) [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data)
- push your entire database to heroku (heroku db:push) [make sure you understand this will wipe out your production database]

Answer (score 3):

Heroku creates a database for each application deployed to it (no need to run `heroku rake db:create`. Here are the commands you should be using to deploy a Rails application to Heroku:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "initial import"
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku rake db:migrate
heroku open
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe Heroku creates a new database.yml for you on deploy if you have no production according to the [Docs](http://groups.google.com/group/heroku/browse_thread/thread/cfa3ad5263a9e967?pli=1).

Comment: I post the log file, I still can't find out the problem

Comment: Heroku overwrites your repository `config/database.yml` with its own `config/database.yml` file, with the appropriate entries for connecting to the database. It's probably a symlink, but it ends up being the same. The general Capistrano and Chef-Deploy recipes employ the same strategy, so it's not unique to Heroku.

Comment: Right, but he was asking how to create the database. Which I believe Heroku does for you.